# Need some help regarding my mongodb aggregate query

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

I have below aggregate query for querying around 9+ lakhs of record:

```
db.getCollection('Job').aggregate([
  {
    "$sort": {
      "lastUpdatedAt": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "$and": [
        { "lastUpdatedAt": { "$gte": new Date("2019-04-01") } },
        {
          "$or": [
            { "job.scheduledEndTime": { "$lte": new Date("2019-07-15") } },
            { "lastUpdatedAt": { "$lte": new Date("2019-07-15") } }
          ]
        },
        { "reduced": null }
      ]
    }
  },
  { "$project": { "_id": 1 } },
  { "$sort": { "_id": 1 } },
  { "$limit": 100 }
])
```

In above query i have compound indexes created and each field have a separate index also there:

```
{ "lastUpdatedAt": -1, "job.scheduledEndTime": -1, "reduced": 1 }
```

and that's a sparse index because reduced field is not in all the documents that is set by me once i get the result from the above query and after performing some operations in there.

Here's what .explain told me : https://pastebin.com/ERgChr2N

The above query took around 100 to 130 sec to return me the result so is there any way to optimise the above query.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello all i changed my query to find one and i get all the result in less-than 1 sec here's my find query :

```
db.getCollection('Job').find({ $and: [ 
    { lastUpdatedAt: {$gte: new Date("2019-04-01")} }, 
    { "$or": [
        {"job.scheduledEndTime":{"$lte": new Date("2019-07-15")}},
        {"lastUpdatedAt":{"$lte": new Date("2019-07-15")}}
    ] },
    { reduced: null }
]}, {_id: 1}).sort({_id: 1}).limit(100)
```